# Problem from Evans' PDE book, chapter 5, problem 5

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm taking my first theoretical math course in a year and am bashing my head against a rock with this problem.

"The sets $U,V$ are open, with $V \subset \subset U $ (compactly contained). Show that there exists a smooth function $\zeta$ such that $\zeta \equiv 1$ on V, $\zeta = 0$ near $\delta U$. (Hint: Take $V \subset \subset W \subset \subset U $ and mollify $\chi_{W}$.)

Now, I've figured that $\chi_{W}$ has to be 1 on $W$ and 0 elsewhere, and that the clue is to mollify $\chi_{W}$ so that the function spends the space between $\delta V$ and $\delta U$ going to zero. How to formalise this into mathematics and "show" it... I'm at a fault. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Do you know how to mollify it?

Comment: Yes, they are to be mollified by the standard mollifier as defined in Evans' book. It is picked on here: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pde_notes.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you need to find a space $W$ satisfying $V\subset\subset W \subset\subset U$ is that you need to smoothly extend the function from set $V$, which takes value 1 to the set close to the boundary of $U$, which takes value $0$. So consider the classical solution of Laplace equation with scale and shift terms included to match the structure.

Comment: Here a solution is provided in http://www.columbia.edu/~la2462/Problems%20from%20Evans.pdf              On page 5, "$w$ is smooth and has support in $W\cap B(0,\epsilon)$, " I am having trouble writing it formally, knowing that it is about checking the $C^{\infty}$ property of the mollifier. In particular, to show derivative exists for high order, how exactly can be done? Induction?